# using R to estimate finite mixture model with underlying Markov process

Tags: r, statistics, markov-chains, mixture-model

My apologies if this is more of a statistics question than an R question. I am trying to estimate the following model in R.

y_t = mu0 (1 - S_t) + mu1 S_t + e_t    e_t ~ N(0, sigma_t^2)
sigma_t^2 = sigma_0^2 (1 - S_t) + sigma_1^2 S_t

where mu_t = mu0 if S_t = 0, mu_t = mu1 if S_t = 1, and S_t is a Markov process, either 0 or 1, with transition probabilities P(S_t = 1 | S_t-1 = 1 ) = p and P(S_t = 0 | S_t-1 = 0 ) = q.

Would 'flexmix' be a good library to use for this? I am new to this kind of statistics so any pointer to the right library would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: I would say that, given the relationship between your parameters, you would be best coding in this logic yourself using R's control structures (in a similar vain to my answer to your last question.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like the exactly type of model you could easily code up in [Bugs](http://www.mrc-bsu.cam.ac.uk/bugs/) or [Jags](http://www-fis.iarc.fr/~martyn/software/jags/).  Bugs/Jags is probably the most flexible approach to estimating custom models in R.  You can easily move between R and Jags using [R2Jags](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R2jags/index.html).

If you are new to Bayesian models, it may take a bit to get up to speed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I think what I want to estimate is a Markov-switching ARCH model. I am trying to duplicate the results of this paper:

http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/0304405X89900949

I know there is the MSVAR package, which isn't quite what I want. Maybe fMarkovSwitching, although that looks like it isn't maintained at the moment. Maybe bayesGARCH? Any experience with any of those? Thanks for the help.

Comment: I doubt this model is implemented in any standard package.  The paper uses the EM algorithm.  Setting the model up in a Bayesian framework, using Jags, is generally much easier and more robust.  However, you will need to specify some priors that aren't in the paper.

I assume you're doing this for academic reasons.  A finite-state markov model does not seem particularly compelling in the real world.

Comment: Hi Tristan, yes I am doing this for academic reasons, just trying to learn more about this particular model. I'll give Jags a shot. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Sorry for bumping this answer, but I would like to try a similar thing so that's why I ask. I am quite familiar with Jags, but could you tell me how you can code a (first-order) markov chain in JAGS? How can you define states?